# Without using NSPredicate i want to get data out from array of dictioary

Tags: ios, nsarray, nspredicate

This is my code how i am currently accessing that data from array of Dictionary but i know there is simple and optimize code to do that .i am new in ios

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"description LIKE[cd] 'CallCenterPhoneNumber' "];
NSArray *PhoneNumberArrary = [tblData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSDictionary *item = [PhoneNumberArrary objectAtIndex:0];
phoneNumber=[item objectForKey:@"value"];
NSLog(@"%@",phoneNumber);
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"description LIKE[cd] 'CallCenterEmailAddress' "];
NSArray *EmailArrary = [tblData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSDictionary *item1 = [EmailArrary objectAtIndex:0];
EmailAddress=[item1 objectForKey:@"value"];
NSLog(@"%@",EmailAddress);
//and this is my array of Dictionary.
(
    {
    description = CallCenterPhoneNumber;
    id = 0;
    value = 123;
    },
    {
    description = CallCenterEmailAddress;
    id = 1;
    value = "email@domain.com";
     },
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in tblData) {
    if ([dictionary.description rangeOfString:@"CallCenterPhoneNumber" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        phoneNumber = dictionary;
    } else  if ([dictionary.description rangeOfString:@"CallCenterEmailAddress" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        emailAddress = dictionary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each entry of the array using a `for ( ... in ... )` loop, and extract information from each dictionary using the simplified syntax. For example, if `entry` is a pointer to a dictionary, then

```
entry[@"description"];
```

is equivalent to

```
[entry objectForKey:@"description"];
```

---

```
    id phoneNumber = nil;
    id emailAddress = nil;

    for ( NSDictionary *entry in array )
    {
        NSString *description = entry[@"description"];

        if ( [description isEqualToString:@"CallCenterPhoneNumber"] )
            phoneNumber = entry[@"value"];
        else if ( [description isEqualToString:@"CallCenterEmailAddress"] )
            emailAddress = entry[@"value"];
    }

    NSLog( @"%@", phoneNumber );
    NSLog( @"%@", emailAddress );
```

Comment: It is best not to usr `id`, instead use the actual type, in this case `NSString`. Doing so allows the compiler to perform type checking and auto-completion.

Comment: @Zaph Actually, it's not clear whether `phoneNumber` is an `NSString` or an `NSNumber`. It could be either, and `id` works with both. However, I agree with you that OP should use the proper type based on how the array was created.

Comment: The person writing the code knows since they need to be handled differently. Using `id` makes later maintenance difficult.